# Show data using compact laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I have a user employee table in database like below

```
id |    name        |            email                |     pic
1     Michael             michael@mic.com                    4
2     John Doe            john.doe@gmail.com                 4
3     Lorem Ipsum         lorem@ipsum.com                    4
4     Dolor Amet           dolor@amet.com                    5
5     Campus Criteria    campus@criteria.com
```

I want to show a data when user id 5 login, he can view his team, User id 5 is pic for user id 4, and user id 4 is pic for user id 1,2 and 3

Here's what I want

```
    Dolor Amet   
 -----------------------------------------------    
    Michael             michael@mic.com                    
    John Doe            john.doe@gmail.com                 
    Lorem Ipsum         lorem@ipsum.com
```

I have tried using compact code, but it's just showing the user id 4, not user id 1,2 and 3

Here's my view right now, it's only view user id 4, user id 1,2 and 3 doesn't show up

```
    Dolor Amet   
 -----------------------------------------------
```

Here's my controller code

```
 public function user($id)
{
    $pic=Users::where('pic',$id)->get();

    foreach($pic as $pics)
    {
        //dd($pics->id);
        $use=Users::where('pic',$pics->id)->get();
    }

    return view('user',compact(['pic','use']));
}
```

Here's my blade code

```
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h3 class="box-title">Your Team</h3>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    @foreach($pic as $pics)
                        <thead class=" text-primary">
                            <th class="text-center">{{ $pics->name }}</th>
                        </thead>
                    @endforeach
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach($use as $uses)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{$uses->name}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Do you know where is the missing ?

Thank you

Comment: switch `compact(['pic','use'])` with `compact('pic','use')`.

Comment: Hi @TahaPaksu, still doesn't work, it's still the same result like before

Comment: It's the same result because the problem is your loop overwrites your variable as @Maulik Shah said. This is only an additional thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because old collection replaced with new collection each time when loop execute

Try with this

```
$use = array();
foreach($pic as $pics) {
    $use[] = Users::where('pic',$pics->id)->get();
}
```

Comment: Hi @Maulik Shah, it comes error in the view blade "Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance"

Comment: you have to loop through use and other one for pic because use is array and it contains many collection according query

Comment: `dd` $use you will get idea how data contains.

Comment: Hi @Maulik Shah, so I think the error is in my view, I have tried dd $use in controller and it's working, isn't it

Comment: like this ? 
foreach($pic as $pics)
        {
            $use[]=Users::where('pic',$pics->id)->get();
        }
        dd($use);

Comment: need your output screen when you dd

Comment: array:2 [▼
  0 => Collection {#260 ▼
    #items: array:2 [▼
      0 => Users {#262 ▶}
      1 => Users {#263 ▶}
    ]
  }
  1 => Collection {#256 ▶}
]

Comment: try to loop through $use and in that again loop through $pic. So you need to loop on $use because it contains multiple collection and inside that loop, again loop through on collection which you need because that's also collection

Comment: I am trying foreach $use only but it's still the same error. Is it must loop before show the $use result ?

Comment: I need your dd output snapshot, so I can say precisely that what you should to do

Comment: dd in view or in controller ?

Comment: As you said you can get your desired data from controller so I need view's dd

Comment: I am using simple foreach , @foreach($use as $uses)
                        {
                            
                                {{ $uses->name }}
                            
                        }
                        @endforeach

Comment: @foreach($use as $uses) { {{ $uses}} } @endforeach ,if you did this as I shown what you get, means like in [{}] or in { }. If you get data in [{}] then you have to loop on that otherwise you can get directly

Comment: Hi @Maulik Shah, when I updated the value in table, why is view in blade is not change ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is correct code for controller :-

```
public function user($id)
{
    $pic=Users::where('id',$id)->get();

    foreach($pic as $pics)
    {
        //dd($pics->id);
        $use=Users::where('pic',$pics->id)->get();
    }

    return view('cobauser',compact(['pic','use']));
}
```

Comment: Hi @Pramod Pandey, still doesn't work, it's still the same result like before

Comment: @IkramShabri When i pass userid 4 i get the result you have shown. I haven't change anything in view.

Answer (score 0):

Use array_push method for combine the array and make compact

```
public function user($id)
{
$pic=Users::where('id',$id)->get();

$array_combine=array();
foreach($pic as $pics)
{

    $use=Users::where('pic',$pics->id)->get();
    array_push($array_combine,$use);
}

return view('cobauser',compact(['pic','array_combine']));
}
```

Comment: Hi @venkatachalapathy, it comes error in the view blade "Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance"

Answer (score 0):

In top of your controller add `use Illuminate\Support\Collection`,

```
public function user($id)
{
    $pic=Users::where('pic',$id)->get();
    // use collection
    $users = new Collection();

    foreach($pic as $pics)
    {
        //dd($pics->id);
        // merge collection with existing content
        $users = $users->merge(Users::where('pic',$pics->id)->get());
    }

    return view('user',compact('pic','users'));
}
```